# Why we need the ancient solution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mean-curvature-flows

Recently, I read the

*Angenent, Sigurd B.*, Shrinking doughnuts, Nonlinear diffusion equations and their equilibrium states, Proc. 3rd Conf., Gregynog/UK 1989, Prog. Nonlinear Differ. Equ. Appl. 7, 21-38 (1992). [ZBL0762.53028](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0762.53028).

and

*Daskalopoulos, Panagiota; Hamilton, Richard; Sesum, Natasa*, [**Classification of compact ancient solutions to the curve shortening flow**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1279114297), J. Differ. Geom. 84, No. 3, 455-464 (2010). [ZBL1205.53070](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1205.53070).

I don't know why they study the ancient solution ?  What is the mean of  the class of  ancient solution  ?

Comment: Note that "ancient solution" is a technical term. As Wikipedia says, "In mathematics, an ancient solution to a differential equation is a solution that can be extrapolated backwards to all past times, without singularities." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_solution

Comment: I think Ancient solutions are often studied because of their relevance in various physics problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short. The study of ancient solution to MCF is vital in understanding the formation of singularity in MCF.

Let $\{ M_t : [0,T) \}$ be a family of smooth MCF in $\mathbb R^n$ which becomes singular at time $T$ at $X\in \mathbb R^n$ (that is, the curvature is unbounded around $X$). Then for any $T_i \to T$, $X_i \to X$ and $\lambda_i \to +\infty$, the sequence of MCF

$$\{ \lambda_i (M_{ \lambda_i^{-2}t + T_i} -X_i) : t \in (-\lambda_i^2 T_i, T_i -T)\}$$

converges to an ancient solution to MCF $\{ M^\infty_ t: t\in (-\infty, 0)\}$. This is called a blow up of the original MCF at $X$.

The idea (indeed, the central idea) is that if you know enough about those ancient solutions that arise from this blowup procedure, then you know a lot about the singularity.

There are lots of such example, but I just point you to the [recent advance](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.08467), where they proved the mean convex neighborhood conjecture in $\mathbb R^3$ by classifying all ancient solutions with low entropy.